# Detained in Canadian airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

My boyfriend was on layover headed to us. They detained him for some kind of contraband in luggage that he didn't know of. He has been held for two and a half days. They took his phone, but allowed him to use it yesterday. I heard nothing since. Do they keep phone like this? How long will they? Can they legally hold him?

Comment: Welcome Vickie. Are you saying he was headed to the United States? Is he an American citizen and, if not, what is his citizenship?

Comment: Get an attorney. You can do nothing by yourself. Hopefully this is a **real boyfriend and not a scammer**. I am very suspicious. Canada is not noted for such treatment of people. Have you two ever met? Cyber romance?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen It sounds a little like the boyfriend may have been an unwitting mule, but it's hard to be sure from the scanty information in the question.

Answer (score 5):

If he was carrying something that is subject to import restrictions, but is otherwise legal, then he would normally be released immediately with a fine, unless he chose to challenge the decision, in which case he'll have to remain for the duration of the trial. If he attempted to bring an illegal substance or item into the country, he could face criminal charges, which naturally could take anywhere from weeks to years to be resolved.